# PHP preg_match with file_get_contents empty array match

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents

I try to extract data with **preg_match**

```
<?php
$HTML   = '#a#TEXT#a#';
$REGEX  = '/#a#(.*?)#a#/';

preg_match($REGEX, $HTML, $MATCH);

print_r($MATCH);
var_dump($MATCH);
?>
```

This works fine.
But if i try the same from a file with **file_get_contents**

This is the input file file.php:
**#a#TEXT#a#**

```
<?php

$HTML   = file_get_contents("file.php");
$REGEX  = '/#a#(.*?)#a#/';

preg_match($REGEX, $HTML, $MATCH);

print_r($MATCH);
var_dump($MATCH);
?>
```

The array $MATCH is empty where is my error?

If the file is like:
`#a#TEXT#a#`
that works!

But if the file is in multiple lines (with breaks) like that::

```
#a#

TEXT

#a#
```

It doesn't work. How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex that help me to match any character across multiple lines :

```php
$REGEX = '/#a#(.*?)#a#/s';
```

I put an **s** on my regex it works

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file is being correctly read?
Try a var_dump($HTML); after you load the file. If it's False, then the file could not be read

Comment: With echo and var_dump i get  the content, but not with preg_match.

Comment: This is the var_dump() outout after the read.   string(13) "#a#TEXT#a#"

Comment: @z4o you do realize that `#a#TEXT#a#` is ten characters, and that the debug output says `string(13)`, yes? So apparently there is something more contained in the value, that you don't see. (Probably a BOM, so make sure you saved `file.php` as UTF-8 without BOM.)